# Mule: synchronize mule flows based on file availability

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have 2 flows that process nodes.flow and relationships.flow and eventually both the flows write to a Database.

Nodes and Relationships are read from separate tsv files and read through fileconnector endpoint

I want to synchronize the flows so that nodes.tsv should always get processed before relationships.tsv. Something like this:

- If only nodes.tsv is present - process it..
- If only relationships.tsv is present wait till nodes.tsv shows up on disk and process nodes.tsv before relationships.tsv..

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your specs, the only file inbound endpoint you need is one that waits for the nodes.tsv file.

When this file is picked-up, process it as expected.

Then, further in the flow, use:

```
    <scripting:component>
        <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
          muleContext.client.request('file:///....../relationships.tsv', eventContext.timeout)
        ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>

    <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="false">
        <not-filter>
            <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.transport.NullPayload" />
        </not-filter>
    </message-filter>
```

to pick-up the relationships file. If it doesn't exist, the filter will stop the flow there. If it exists, then what's after in the flow will be able to process it.

Comment: Thanks David, Sorry didnt get a chance to try this out earlier.. This solution is elegant.. but my requirements have changed so I cannot use it as is I will this keep this in mind for future..

Answer (score 1):

By default the file endpoints will process when a file appears in the target dir, so I would dispense with one of the endpoints and in your master one just pull the slave file in like so:

```
muleClient.request('file://D:/foo/in', -1);
```

Alternatively have a file name filter on the slave flow and then have your master flow rename the files in the slave dir to match the file filter.

Comment: Thanks for.. I like the 2nd idea. But regarding your first idea, if both files are present together, how can I give precedence to  nodes.tsv over relationships.tsv?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd Idea.. I think of using file:outbound endpoint, but it references the file "currently" being transferred into the flow. How do I make it reference the file to be renamed on disk? (to pass file filter)

Comment: use 2 separate inbound endpoints for the precedence. Once it renames the event will be triggered on the slave flow